# Capture return code from Expect

Tags: linux, shell, powershell, ssh, expect

Trying to execute expect script from linux machine to capture return code of powershell script which is placed in windows machine.

**run.sh**

```
expect ssh.exp $USER $HOST $PASSWD "PowerShell -NonInteractive -NoProfile -Command test.ps1"
```

**ssh.exp**

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

set user [lindex $argv 0];
set host [lindex $argv 1];
set pass [lindex $argv 2];
set cmd [lindex $argv 3];


spawn ssh -C -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no -oCheckHostIP=no $user@$host

expect "password:"
send "$pass\r"

expect -re ".*?>"
send "$cmd\r"

expect -re ".*?>"
send "exit\r"

interact
```

**test.ps1**

```
function test {
    $i = 1
    if ($i -eq 2) {
        Write-Host "success"
    }
    else {
        Write-Host "failed"
        $host.SetShouldExit(5)
        exit
    }
}
Write-Host "Exiting with code 5"
test
```

Expected Return Code : **5**

Comment: Don't just throw code like this, you should explain your 3 codes to improve the possible answers

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at the exit status:

```
send "$cmd\r"
expect -re ".*?>"

send "echo \$lastexitcode\r"
expect -re {\y(\d+)\y.*>}
set exit_status $expect_out(1,string)

send "exit\r"
expect eof
```